# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException- App.Shell

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

When running my Xamarin.Forms shell app in Visual Studio for Mac I ran into an issue when clicking on one of the buttons that is supposed to take me to one of the screens: A message is received "Exception Caught". [The Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP4FQ.jpg). Something is wrong with Main.cs file in line 15. All the other events in the app are working properly.
Does anyone know how the error can be resolved?
The code: Main.cs

```
{using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace Rollthedice3._0.iOS

    {
        public class Application
        {
            // This is the main entry point of the application.
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                UIApplication.Main(args, null, typeof(AppDelegate)); //line 15
            }
        }
    }
    
    }
```

The xaml code of the page that induces the exception:
{

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Rollthedice3._0.Views.LoginPage"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">


    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Accent}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
           
            </StackLayout>








        </Grid>
         

        
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Open the 'Exception Settings'

[image]

Click on 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions' and make sure it has a check [image]

[image]

Now run your program again.

After you finished debugging, restore the settings back to the default.

[image]